# Calculating sine values in javascript using for loop, but it keeps crashing. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, html5-canvas

So I'm trying to calculate values of the function sin(x) by inputting a domain parameter and how many steps to calculate the y values for each respective x value. I know the for loop is the problem because when I comment it out, the page loads fine. However, if the loop is active, then the page crashes.

I thought, "oh, maybe it's because I am looping numbers that are irrational such as PI". Well, I changed the domain to [0, 2] so that the numbers are more "nice", but I still get the same issue.

I tried looking up possible reasons why this is happening, and it seems to be because of some sort of recursion happening somewhere. I don't know where. The code looks right as far as I can tell. Is it possibly be because I don't have enough memory or something?

By the way, I am doing this because I am making a graphing program using HTML5 canvas just for fun and practice.

```
//domain is the closed interval you want the function to be calculated on [a,b]
//numSteps is the accuracy of your graph

function sinGraph(domain, numSteps) {
  //prepare x and y value arrays
  var yVal = [];
  var xVal = [];

  //check if the function parameters are acceptable
  if (domain[0] == domain[1] || numSteps <= 0) {
    alert("Invalid inputs. Domain must be in format [a, b] where a does not equal b. Number of steps must be greater than zero.");
  } else {

    //define interval length
    var intLength = Math.abs(domain[1] - domain[0]);

    //find the number of steps
    var stepSize = intLength / numSteps;

    //calculate y values based on x values
    //push x and y values into arrays based on numSteps
    for (var i = domain[0]; i<=domain[1]; i+stepSize) {
      var xTemp = i;
      var yTemp = Math.sin(i);
      xVal.push(xTemp);
      yVal.push(yTemp);
    }

    //return x and y value arrays
    return {
      xVal: xVal,
      yVal: yVal
    };

  }

}

//test
var graph = sinGraph([0, Math.PI], 20);
alert(graph.yVal);
```

Comment: what crash? the browser? you get an error? what error? do all inputs fail?

Comment: The browser (Chrome) crashes. Says, "Not enough memory to open this page."

Comment: The third part of your `for` loop, `i+stepSize`, is likely the culprit as you never change the value of `i`. I suggest `i+=stepSize`

Comment: Thank you so much! I overlooked that. I'm just used to using i++ so I thought you can increment by other values the same way. I forgot that you have to reassign the value.

Comment: weird it crash chrome instead of just timeout

Comment: @Forty3 you should post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a minor typo in the incremental portion of the `for` loop:

```
//calculate y values based on x values
//push x and y values into arrays based on numSteps
for (var i = domain[0]; i<=domain[1]; i += stepSize) {
  var xTemp = i;
  var yTemp = Math.sin(i);
  xVal.push(xTemp);
  yVal.push(yTemp);
}
```